# Как использовать переменные из одной класса в другом?

Tags: python, ооп, классы, методы, переменные

Хочу использовать переменные другой функции внутри класса, но их почему-то не видит функция. 
Как можно это сделать?

Не видит во второй функции параметры `question_1` и `dificulti`.

```
class AskQuestion(Question):

    def ask(self, question_1):
        question_1 = random.choice(list(question_1))
        question_q = question_1["q"]
        dificulti = question_1["d"]
        return self.build_question(question_q, dificulti)


class AnswerQuestion(AskQuestion):

    def answer(self, question_2):
        ans = AskQuestion()
        ans.ask(question_2)
        answer_player = input()
        question_r = question_1["a"]
        self.is_correct(answer_player, question_r )
        self.get_point(dificulti)
        print(dificulti)
```

Comment: 1 - не очень понятно, зачем целый класс для одного метода. 2 - в принципе, если метод ответственен за запрос ответа, то он не должен заниматься формулировкой вопроса, и проверкой ответа.

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: я хочу использовать переменные question_1 и dificulti во второй функции, но их не видит функция, поэтому не понимаю что делать, глобал тоже пыталась делать

Comment: Яна, ваш вопрос не очень понятен. 1. Для чего вы наследуете класс `AnswerQuestion` от класса `AskQuestion`, а затем в методе `answer()` создаете экземпляр класса `AskQuestion()`  ?

Comment: Потому что надо чтобы использовалась функция из прошлого класса в этой функции при ее вызове, конечно можно их отдельно вызвать, но так мне проще, проблема же в другом

Answer (score 2):

Яна, хотя вы не ответили ни на один мой комментарий и я совсем не понимаю что вы хотите сделать.

Но учитывая что это ваш первый вопрос, попробуйте так:

```
import random


class AskQuestion(Question):
    dificulti = None                                           # +++
    question_1 = None                                          # +++

    def ask(self, question_1):
# ----> vvvv <------------------------------------------------------    
        self.question_1 = random.choice(list(question_1))
# ???                # ??? или что
        question_q = question_1["q"]
# ----> vvvv <------------------------------------------------------
        self.dificulti = self.question_1["d"]
# -------------------------------------------> vvvv <---------------
        return self.build_question(question_q, self.dificulti)


class AnswerQuestion():                                     # ? AskQuestion
    def answer(self, question_2):
# ----> vvvv <------------------------------------------------------
        self.ans = AskQuestion()
# ----> vvvv <------------------------------------------------------
        self.ans.ask(question_2)
        answer_player = input()
# -----------------> vvvvvvvvv <-------------
        question_r = self.ans.question_1["a"]
        self.is_correct(answer_player, question_r )
# -------------------> vvvvvvvv <-----------------------------------
        self.get_point(self.ans.dificulti)
# ----------> vvvvvvvvv <-------------------------------------------
        print(self.ans.dificulti)
```

Comment: ругается на строчку self.dificulti = self.question_1["d"]

Comment: так же ругается если хочу вызвать функцию ask в конце

Comment: немного исправила код, потому что заметила, что не все так же переписала, теперь ругается на quest.answer(question), а переменная quest = AnswerQuestion(), question это словарь с данными, self.ans.ask(question_2) ругается на это, а так же на это self.dificulti = self.question_1["d"]

Comment: @ЯнаРоманенко , забудьте слово `ругается`. 
Вы должны четко говорить о конкретной ошибке и показывать ее 
полное содержание. Попробуйте поставить принты в проблемных местах. 
Посмотрите что такое `self.question_1` и что такое `question_1` 
и что вы хотите с ним сделать. 
Очень внимательно прочитайте мой первый комментарий и по ссылке в нем. 
Составьте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не сделать один класс вместо двоих?

```
class AskQuestion():
    def ask(self, question_1):
        question_1 = random.choice(list(question_1))
        question_q = question_1["q"]
        dificulti = question_1["d"]
        return self.build_question(question_q, dificulti)


    def answer(self, question_2):
        ans = AskQuestion()
        ans.ask(question_2)
        answer_player = input()
        question_r = question_1["a"]
        self.is_correct(answer_player, question_r )
        self.get_point(dificulti)
        print(dificulti)
```

Вопрос не совсем понятен.

Comment: Задание предполагает использовать несколько классов, поэтому я позаимствовала в классе AnswerQuestion все от другого, по сути объединила в один класс

Comment: даже при использовании одного класса вторая функция не видит переменные question_1 и qificulti